# How Can You Show Columns Associated with Lookup On Select?

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, lookup-column

I've got a lookup column that is pulling another field with it. I am trying to show the other field on a New form when a selection is made from the lookup dropdown.

The user needs to use use this information to make a choice on whether or not to suggest a modification.

How can I pull back the associated information with that lookup selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that out of the box.

If you put some JavaScript on your NewForm.aspx with a Content Editor Web Part or Script Editor Web Part and use JQuery and the SPServices library from Codeplex (https://spservices.codeplex.com), you can do this fairly easily.

This is an example from the Codeplex site:

```
$().SPServices.SPDisplayRelatedInfo({
columnName: "System",
relatedList: "Systems",
relatedListColumn: "Title",
relatedColumns: ["System_x0020_Image", "Lead_x0020_Sales_x0020_Rep"],
displayFormat: "list"
});
```

This displays the fields "System Image" and "Lease Sales Rep" from the Systems lookup list when the field "System" is changed. The value selected in the System field is looked up using the Title field in the Systems list to find the data.